# Custom form control component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to learn Angular. I have tried to do custom form control which has `mat-select` inside and the value I want to submit with the form is the selected item.

After reading whole bunch of tutorials and documentation I have managed to get something like this:
[stripped example of the problem on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uodupb).

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you expect to work? Be more precise please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're way overcomplicating things. You do not need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` for such a simple case. You can just relay the `FormControl` to the child component using a simple `@Input()`.

select.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  providers: [ ]
})

export class SelectorComponent implements  OnInit {
  @Input() ctrl: FormControl;
  @Input() options: string[];

  ngOnInit() {  }
}
```

select.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="ctrl" placeholder="My select">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
            {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpa4xf)